# Probability of being within a standard deviation in a modified random walk?

Tags: probability, random-walk

I am only familiar with the very basics of random walks, so I can not judge how trivial my question is.

Assume that we have a generalised random walk where now instead of the outcomes being $\{1, -1\}$, they are $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n \}$, where $x_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ and with respective probabilities of occurrence $\{p_1,\ldots,p_n\}$.
The expected value for such a generalised random walk at each iteration is:
\begin{equation}
EV=\sum_{i=1}^n p_i m_i .
\end{equation}
After $n$ iterations the expected value will be $EV(n)= EV\cdot n$.
Similarly, one can calculate the variance at each step through
\begin{equation}
Var=\sum_{i=1}^n p_i m_i^2 -EV^2 ,
\end{equation}
and once again after $n$ steps we have $Var(n)=n\cdot Var$. From this it follows that the standard deviation grows as $\sim\sqrt{n}$, as expected for a random walk.

So as a first question, are the above statements correct?

Assuming this is the case, my main question would then be: what is the probability that after $n$ steps I am within one standard deviation from the expected value? How do I calculate it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even in the classic random walk, you will need to work with the Binomial CDF which either you need a computer to do it or need some approximations like the normal one. In your quest I am afraid you will need the same. If you are just interested in a bound on this probability then you have at least Chebyshev's and others.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! When you say "or need some approximations like the normal one", what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Also, Chebyshev's inequality becomes sort of trivial for my question as it gives that the probability is just less than or equal to one...

Comment: I mean the normal approximation due to CLT, when $n$ is large. I think there are other tighter bounds besides Chebyshev.

Comment: OK, I now understand. Thanks for the help!